# trouble in c with characters issue

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){
    char bname,date,sname;
    int scode;
    scanf("%[^\n]s \n %d \n  %[^\n]s \n  %[^\n]s"  ,&bname,&scode,&date,&sname);
    printf(" %s \n %d \n  %s \n  %s"  ,bname,scode,date,sname);
    return 0;

}
```

my need;

i/p:

```
The Alchemist
8741
03/02/2020
Finn Martin
```

o/p:

```
BOOK NAME:The Alchemist
SERIAL CODE:8741
ISSUE DATE:03/02/2020
STUDENT NAME:Finn Martin
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no question visible. What exactly is your problem? What part of "my need" is input, output, expected output?

Comment: `char bname,date,sname;` These are single character variables that can only hold a string of length 0 (including terminating 0 byte). Do you want to use arrays?

Comment: Another problem: You've got some extra `s`'s in your format string.  You'd want `%[^\n]`, not `%[^\n]s`.  (But with that said, `fgets` is usually a better way of reading whole lines.)

Comment: In C, a string is an ***array*** of *null-terminated* characters.

Comment: Ibu, care to explain why my answer was unaccepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `char` array instead of `char`. Also, there are some format issue as pointed out by the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char bname[100],date[100],sname[100];
    int scode;
    scanf("%[^\n]\n%d\n%[^\n]\n%[^\n]"  ,bname, &scode, date, sname);
    printf("BOOK NAME:%s\nSERIAL CODE:%d\nISSUE DATE:%s\nSTUDENT NAME:%s\n"  ,bname,scode,date,sname);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create *arrays* for the strings instead of using single characters, remove the `s` characters from the input format specifier, and remove the spaces from the output format specifier:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char bname[64], date[64], sname[64];
    int scode;
    scanf("%63[^\n]%d %63[^\n] %63[^\n]", bname, &scode, date, sname);
    printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n%s\n", bname, scode, date, sname);
}
```

A space (`' '`) or newline (`'\n'`) character in the input format specifier instructs `scanf` to ignore *all whitespace* starting at that position. The `63`'s specify the maximum width that is read (excluding the null-terminator), which is a good practice to avoid buffer overflows. Although, it is better to avoid `scanf` altogether for safety reasons. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information on `scanf`.

This still does not print the `BOOK NAME`, `SERIAL CODE`, etc., but the problems seemed to lie with reading the data.

Additionally, only the `stdio.h` header is necessary here.

*Credits also go to stark, SteveSummit, Gerhardh and Oka.*

Comment: You aren't printing the field names

Comment: @stark True, I should have comment on that. Reading the data was the problem, I assumed. Printing the field names is trivial.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you. The question has since been updated with a clear input example _not_ showing spaces, so I'll update the answer.

Comment: @SteveSummit Good catch! Answer updated.

Comment: The `scanf` specifier `"%[^\n]"` is [as dangerous as `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). If you *must* teach `scanf`, please at the very minimum instruct others on the use of *field-width specifiers*; e.g. `"%63[^\n]"`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Good suggestion. And no, the `%d` format specifier skips all leading whitespace.

Comment: OK, I always miss that detail. ;)

Comment: @Oka Good point, I agree. Unfortunately, `scanf` is still taught in many courses without mentioning security. Answer has been updated.